# Reproducible PyTorch Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm using PyTorch (1.7.1), PyTorch Geometric (1.6.3), NVIDIA Cuda (11.2).

I need to make a neural network reproducible for a competition.

However, when I try:

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
rand = 123
torch.manual_seed(rand)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(rand)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(rand)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
np.random.seed(rand)
random.seed(rand)
```

the results are different each time I run the code. How can I fix it?

(For a reference, it always comes out the same in `device = torch.device('cpu')`.)

Answer (score 2):

There is this nice function from Kaggle:

```
def seed_everything(seed=1234):
    random.seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

seed_everything()
```

There are several version of this function for torch, tensorflow and combinations. This specific one is from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/bminixhofer/deterministic-neural-networks-using-pytorch).

Run this before you run your model. But not only the fitting function. It needs to be before the validation split function as well.